# read elements from an xml file using SAXReader

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, dom4j

Am trying to read the below xml content using SAXReader
I have to read the child elements of node name `"SelogerListController"`.
The node name `"SelogerListController"` contains 3 child nodes .

My main aim is to get the 3rd node's child elemnts of node name `"SelogerListControllerlike"`

```
 src="http://res/Favorite_Badge.png" ,src="http://res/sm_aries.png"
```

and

```
 src="http://res/sm_cancer.png"  and http://res/Favorite_Badge.png
 ...............
```

and the remining details also..

Code using

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document document;
        String xPath = "//XREClientView/XREClientView[5]";
        String nodeName = null;

        List<Element> childViews;
        try {
            document = reader.read("F://TestNewXMLAfter.xml");

            List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes(xPath);
            for (Node node : nodes) {
                System.out.println("name :: " + node.valueOf("@name"));
                System.out.println(node.getPath());
                nodeName = node.valueOf("@name");
                if (nodeName.equals("SelogerListController")) {
                    childViews = ((Element) node).elements();

                    for (Element element : childViews) {
                        Element ele = element.element("XREClientImage");
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: you can use variable-buffer for current element. when parser done his work you will have last item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath you show in your post is:

```
//XREClientView/XREClientView[5]
```

This says find an `XREClientView` which contains at least five child nodes named `XREClientView` and return the fifth one.  The XPath should start

```
//XREClientView[@name='SelogerListController']/...
```

where you can work out what to substitute for `...`.  It's not entirely clear what unique attribute values you can use to find the nodes you're interested in.

Comment: Did you read the question? I am quoting the OP's attempt, not suggesting he hardcode anything.  That said, given the "interesting" XML schema, there may not be any other way to achieve the OP's goals.

Comment: i have get the child elements of following xpath //XREClientView[@name='SeleogerListController']/XREClientView[3]

Comment: OK, so what's stopping you?  Please edit your original post and explain what is not working.

Comment: here is the code using  String xPath = "//XREClientView[@name='SeleogerListController']/XREClientView[3]";
            List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes(xPath);       from this i need to get the child elements..but i dont know how to get that?it only get only one node...not fetching its child nodes

Comment: Do not post code in comments, EDIT your original post.